# How to create C++ MDI mfc child windows using code?

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, mdichild

Using MFC Wizard i have create one MDI code, how i can create a child windows using code?

I think it's something like:

```
CMyAppDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();​ 
ASSERT(pDoc);​
```

Thanks

Comment: You would want to use the 'Open Document' method, even if you don't have a file for input. Then the doc manager will handle creating the Frame and View.

Comment: @lakeweb what is the most correct way?, I have different types of data to display then graphs... or MFC List Control(goods)

Comment: I always typically let the doc manager create the frame and view. Then it is just a few lines of code and you don't have to do extra work. How ever you derive your doc and view for a job, let the doc manager create them for you.